# Action filters across dashboards without switching sheets in Tableau 9.2

Tags: filter, tableau-api

In Tableau 9.2, how can I use a filter which filters from one dashboard to another so that when I trigger it, it does **not** switch dashboards?  I have found [this](https://community.tableau.com/thread/193158?start=0&tstart=0) answer online, yet the poster cautions that their method should only be used for V7 and not V9.

Comment: Just curious, why filter a view if you aren't going to display it? Is the expectation that the user will apply several filtering steps, and then switch?

Comment: You may want to select data based on some line/bar charts and maps on one view and then move further to another view (the one we don't want to switch to immediately) to see a detailed view of only those selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create another action as a filter in the sheet you want to stay in and select all of the dashboards as source and target. As this is the newest action it should make you stay in the same sheet while you keep applying different filters to your data.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dashboard Menu go to Actions and add a Filter,in the filter select source dashboard and select other dashboard as target.This will redirect you to different tab.

Comment: That is the exact opposite of what I am trying to do.  From my question, I intend to have a filter action that doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter along with calculated fields, or use the JavaScript API

Filter actions also change to the target sheet or dashboard, if not already in focus (as you found out)

If you are doing single selection and your list of values is relatively stable, you could use a parameter instead -- loading the initial values from your field. And then define calculated fields that access the parameter value and use those fields on filter shelves as desired.

Changing a parameter value does not change the view to a target sheet -- unlike a filter action.

The downside of this approach is that the parameter values are not loaded dynamically from a data source and that parameters can only have a single value.

Another option could be to use the JavaScript API in some way. You could listen for changes to the selection, and take whatever action you want in response. That only works if you publish to Tableau Server, and you may want to then pull out some of the navigation controls into your own HTML/CSS -- say to filter the second dashboard just before switching to it.